# unable to deploy war files since running ofbiz?

Tags: tomcat, war, ofbiz

I have a OFBIZ source code which is currently running in a linux server machine.Now i want to deploy another application which is in WAR Format in the same server.Since OFBIZ trunc has its own built in tomcat server.

help me to overcome this issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the expanded war inside the hot-deploy folder.

See this link: http://osdir.com/ml/java.ofbiz.user/2008-09/msg00313.html